# How do I recover my pre-Kerl IOTA balance?

Tags: iota-recovery, kerl, curl

I bought IOTA in August and transferred the coins to my IOTA wallet.  Then IOTA network changed the hash function from Curl to Kerl.  Now my IOTA balance shows as zero.  How do I transition my IOTA across the Curl/Kerl breaking change?

Comment: if i use the reclaim tool do i create a new seed myself?

Comment: yes with iota you always create the seed yourself!

Answer (score 4):

There is a **[reclaim tool](https://blog.iota.org/gui-v2-5-2-latest-release-with-iota-reclaim-tool-32d364d6241a)** built into the IOTA Light Wallet since version 2.5.2.

Just download the wallet and

- click on `Tools > Reclaim tool`.
- enter your old seed
- enter your [new seed](https://iotasupport.com/gui-newseed.shtml)
- click *CONTINUE*
- now you the Hash of your "Proof Transaction" will be displayed

Once the transaction is confirmed (reattach if necessary), the IOTA foundation knows that you are in fact the owner of your tokens. After they processed your transaction your funds are available on the new seed.

Comment: You will receive the IOTA once your confirmed transaction is processed by the IOTA foundation (so not instantaneously). There is currently some backlog of reclaim transactions, so it may take a few days/weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are upgraded to the newest IOTA wallet. If your balance is zero that means your wallet is connecting. Generate a new receive address and attach it to the tangle and wait a few minutes. If your balance is still zero, generate another receive address and attach it to the tangle and wait. If you have made several transactions using your wallet before the change you may have to repeat this several times to retrieve all of your balance. If this fails you will have to use the reclaim tool in the menu of your IOTA wallet GUI.